# Convert string using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, match

I'm trying to replace this string:

```
String str2 = "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29027000/Points Of Interest/totem,"
          + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29044000/Places/Italia,"
          + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29027000/Military Equipment";
```

into:

```
String str2 = "/EMOTIONS_TAX/22/Points Of Interest/totem,"
           + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/22/Places/Italia,"
           + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/22/Military Equipment/sica";
```

So, I want to replace all long numbers in the string with `"22"`.

Can you explain how can I do that?

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Comment: What research did you do so far? Where exactly do you have problems? Is it using google, understanding regex or using them correctly?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand how specify a text between backslash (/) or pipe (|).

Comment: this identifies the numbers between slashes /(\d+)/

Comment: Try `(?<=EMOTIONS_TAX\/)(\d+)` replacing with `22` [here](https://regex101.com/r/gZnpgb/1)

Comment: ok,it works. And If i want only extract all long numbers with prefix /(any strings)/(\d+) from the string, (without replacing) ?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can achieve it by `regex` as follow if you want to just replace the **long number**:

```
    String str2 = "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29027000/Points Of Interest/totem,"
    + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29044000/Places/Italia,"
    + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29027000/Military Equipment";

    str2 = str2.replaceAll("\\d+", "22");
```

And the result will be:

```
/EMOTIONS_TAX/22/Points Of Interest/totem,/EMOTIONS_TAX/22/Places/Italia,/EMOTIONS_TAX/22/Military Equipment
```

#### UPDATED

As OP's request, OP tries to retrieve the **number** from the string instead actually and the solution should be:

```
    String str2 = "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29027000/Points Of Interest/totem,"
                  + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29044000/Places/Italia,"
                  + "/EMOTIONS_TAX/29027000/Military Equipment";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str2);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

And the output:

```
29027000
29044000
29027000
```

Comment: ok,thank you!!. And If i want only extract all long numbers with prefix /(any strings)/(\d+) from the string, (without replacing) ?Thank you

Comment: `extract all long numbers with prefix /(any strings)/(\d+)`? A case demo for your idea?

Comment: `/EMOTIONS_TAX/22` only this for `/EMOTIONS_TAX/29027000/Points Of Interest/totem`?

Comment: Sorry, I try to explain better. I want to extract 29027000,29044000, 29027000 from initial string (str2), so all string of numbers. I think I have to write a pattern of the str2 and then extract the substring ("\\d+") of it, isn't it?

Comment: Wow, in that case, the solution is totally different. Let me update the solution for that. Please upvote the solution if it's good to you ~~

Answer (score -1):

```
String result = str2.replaceAll("/\\\d+/", "/22/");
```

Comment: `/pattern/` are JS constructs, just use `pattern` in Java